# Contract metaphor for preconditions and postconditions

Tags: vocabulary, metaphors, programming

English is not my primary language but I'm "forced" to write code and code's comments in English. I'm now trying to develop a PHP code (doesn't really matter this aspect) like this:

```
function divide($x, $y) {}
```

Which describes a function that divide $x / $y. Now I want to be able to add a comment related to that function listing few pre-conditions such as

```
@[A]: $x is an int
@[A]: $y is an int
@[A]: $y != 0
```

and a list of post-conditions (that are verified only if the pre-conditions are respected), such as:

```
@[B]: returns $x / $y
```

How should I call `[A]` and `[B]` using a contract metaphor?

Something like [A] = "law" and [B] = "assurance" (which is obliviously wrong). How should I better call them to make it appears that

> If you follow all the [A]s I'll guarantee you that [B] will be
>   verified.

?

Comment: For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: I'm afraid this site is the wrong place to post.  See the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions): "please, don’t ask any questions about these topics: ... How to name this function/variable in my program"

Comment: @Danielδ, I didn't read that :P Sorry. But this is not about a variable or a function but about commenting which is somehow just writing.

Comment: It's my turn to apologize - I didn't follow your question closely enough.

Comment: In my experience the whole thing -- preconditions, function spec, and postconditions -- is the contract.

Comment: +1 for _obliviously wrong,_ a bon mot if I ever heard one.

Comment: And now I find I'm not allowed to post the answer I just spent a half hour on before it was closed, despite assurances that that sort of thing shouldn't happen. Too bad.

Comment: @JohnLawler, post it here in a comment. It's not all about the reputation right?

Comment: It's too long, and probably the formatting's wrong, but I'll try.

Comment: Yes, it won't let me post it because the format's wrong. "An error occured during comment submission." Correct.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I don't see how anyone could possibly truthfully give you assurances that 'that sort of thing shouldn't happen' namely closing before you finish typing; that's just how the software works (and to do otherwise would be a complex design). That's just poor luck. One strategy to allay your annoyance: submit a draft or exec summary sooner rather than later, then edit to submit the complete lengthy answer.

Comment: Like I said, too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *[stipulation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stipulation)* and *[guarantee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guarantee)*.

**stipulation:**

> something stipulated; especially : a condition, requirement, or item
>   specified in a legal instrument

**guarantee**

> an assurance for the fulfillment of a condition: as

Comment: you are quite welcome!

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the [Design-by-contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) webpage mentioned in a comment, conditions on inputs are known as *[preconditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition)*, and on outputs as *[postconditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition)*.  Of the former, wikipedia says:

> A precondition is a condition or predicate that must always be true just prior to the execution of some section of code or before an operation in a formal specification.
>   If a precondition is violated, the effect of the section of code becomes undefined and thus may or may not carry out its intended work.

and of [postconditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition) it says

> A postcondition is a condition or predicate that must always be true just after the execution of some section of code or after an operation in a formal specification.

*Edit:* You could also use phrasings like "The caller agrees to ...", "If these stipulated conditions are met, the routine will...", "Given that ..., the routine is required to ...".  You might also refer to the preconditions as "Requirements" or "Stipulations", and the postconditions as "Guarantees" or "Undertakings".  Mix and match to similar effect. For example:

> If the caller meets stipulations P,Q,R, the program undertakes to deliver X,Y,Z.
>   If the caller satisfies requirements P,Q,R, the program guarantees it will return X,Y,Z.

Comment: Yep, sorry, but I'd like not to use PRE/Precondition or POST/Postcondition for a trauma closely related to these words I got recently (not kidding). And I'd love to be more metaphor-likely using abstract words referring to the contract itself. Maybe something formal.

Comment: If you are writing in-code comments, precondition  and postcondition probably are the terms you should use, in spite of personal preference.

Comment: Something like "Contract" and "Guarantees"? Like, "If you sign this contract I'll give you these guarantees?"

Comment: @CharliePigarelli, I updated answer slightly, and deleted a comment.

Comment: @Charlie: If you *know* the precise terms but just don't *like* them, that's too localized and off-topic. Brainstorming metaphors is not the purpose of this site, and not a good fit for the SE format. Sorry.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道, ok, I'm sorry.